# Programming Asynchronous Delegate methods in Swift

Tags: ios, asynchronous, swift, callback, serial-port

I have an application which talks to a device over a BLE UART connection.
When data is received, a didReceiveData() delegate is called.
Here I need determine who called the data and trigger the corresponding method (of another delegate).
I was planning on creating a connections dictionary keyed by a connectionID string created when the connection is established, along with a selector to the callback (may not always be supplied).

```
class Connection: NSObject {
    var selectr: Selector
    var dataString: String?
    init(selectR:Selector,dString:String) {
        selectr = selectR
        dataString = dString
    }
}
connections[String:Connection]()
func sendData(dataString:String,callbackSelector:Selector){
  con = Connection(selectR: callbackSelector, dString:"")
  connections[cid] = con
}
```

...
When calling:

```
    let sel = Selector(anotherDelegate?.didReceiveLocation(""))
    self.sendData("sendMe",Selector(anotherDelegate?.didReceiveLocation))
```

I get a few errors doing this, first a Type NSData does not conform to protocol StringLiteralConvertible. NSData referring to the argument of didReceiveLocation.
The second is on the self.sendData line: Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type (StringLiteralConvertible,Selector).

Does this approach make sense? How can I store the callback method of another delegate in a dictionary or other struct to make it accessible from the didReceiveData delegate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectors are so Objective-C... why not just use a closure?

To declare a dictionary with String as keys and functions that take a String as a parameter and return nothing:

```
connections = [String:String->()]()
```

To declare a function that takes a closure with a single String argument and no return value, use something like:

```
func sendData(dataString:String, callback:String->()) {
    ...
    connections[cid] = callback
    ...
}
```

To invoke that closure later, you can call it as a subroutine (in this case after performing a dictionary lookup, using optional chaining in case it hasn't been assigned yet):

```
func didReceiveData(...) {
    ...
    connections[cid]?(response)
}
```

Then to call the sendData routine declared above and pass in a closure using one of the several abbreviated syntaxes:

```
    self.sendData("sendMe") { response in
        ...
    }
```

Note that this is actually short-hand for:

```
    self.sendData("sendMe", callback:{ response:String in
        ...
    })
```

Note that this mechanism can also be used by an Objective-C caller, since closures map more or less directly to Objective-C blocks.

For more information on closures, their definition and invocation, I'd strongly recommend downloading the free Swift book from the iTunes book store.

Comment: That sounds like what I am looking for, but I am pretty new to closures and a bit confused on the implementation. Is your sendMe() function separate from sendData? If my callback method is anotherDelegate?.foundLocation(String), I call send data like sendData("findLocation","anotherDelegate?.foundLocation(String)")?